# TMS TDBADVGRID field is blank when data has "<C"

Tags: tms, c++builder-xe4

Windows application C++ XE4 using TMS TDBADVGRID and an Oracle database. The data (60 character field) in the field/column of the grid contains "<CONTROL", "<DL,<CONTROL", or "<RL,<DL,<CONTROL", etc. When this data is to be displayed in the grid, the field/column is blank. It is the "<C" that has the issue.

If I change the data to "<LC" or "C>" it works. The customer requires "<CONTROL" as required format. How do I keep the data from being invisible? It doesn't affect the stored data in the table.
I tried changing the type of editor set for the column (None, normal, memofield, custom) and checking showunicode

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solution is: on the Grid set EnableHTML to false. TMS responded to my tech support question.
I should have known.